# MySQL inquery - if a cell is empty then

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I am a noob at MySQL (so keep that in mind, haha).

I am looking for a if/then query that does the following...

Table = schedule_table
Columns = invoice_number, archive

In schedule_table, if invoice_number is not empty then fill archive with yes.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: By "empty" you mean only empty, or also NULL ? because it is a little bit different cases.

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as

```
UPDATE schedule_table
   SET archive = 'Yes'
 WHERE invoice_number IS NOT NULL
```

But, you should check if `invoice_number` contains empty text, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the following code and it changed the whole archive column to yes.   
    UPDATE `schedule_table`    
    SET `archive` = 'yes'    
    WHERE `invoice_num` IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

To cover NULL and empty it has to be somthing like:

```
UPDATE schedule_table
   SET archive = 'Yes'
 WHERE invoice_number IS NOT NULL OR invoice_number=''
```

Comment: Thanks Simion! I ended up setting all of archive to yes then setting archive to no where invoice =''.